# How to Mark Right Angle in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Line MN is perpendicular to lines d1 and d2. I want to put mark right angle at points M and N. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis, width=7in, axis equal image, axis lines=middle,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty, xmin=-1,xmax=15,
ymin=0,ymax=10,]
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:0,8)--(axis cs:12,7);
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:12,4);
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:8,2.6)--(axis cs:8,7.35);
\addplot[only marks, mark options = {black},mark size=2pt] (8,2.6);
\addplot[only marks, mark options = {black},mark size=2pt] (8,7.35);
\node [] at (axis cs:12.5,7) {$d_1$};
\node [] at (axis cs:12.5,4) {$d_2$};
\node [] at (axis cs:8,8) {$M$};
\node [] at (axis cs:8,2) {$N$};
\addplot[only marks, mark options = {black},mark size=2pt] (4,1.3);
\addplot[only marks, mark options = {black},mark size=2pt] (4,7.7);
\node [] at (axis cs:4,0.6) {$Q=\left( 2,7,-17\right)$};
\node [] at (axis cs:4,8.3) {$P=\left( -3,-4,-5\right)$};
\addplot[only marks, mark options = {black},mark size=2pt] (0,4);
\node [] at (axis cs:-0.5,4) {$O$};
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:0,4)--(axis cs:4,1.3);
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:0,4)--(axis cs:4,7.7);
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:0,4)--(axis cs:8,2.6);
\draw[very thick] (axis cs:0,4)--(axis cs:8,7.35);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYkc6.png]

Comment: The `angles` library has a `right angle` pic. However, I am wondering why you plot this with `pgfpfplots`, in particular in the way you do.

Comment: I am not an expert about this topic. If you have a better answer I will be glad

Comment: I do not know what you want to draw here since you mix 3d and 2d coordinates.

Comment: I want to draw two skew lines in 3D

Comment: @M.O. You should provide context of the picture such as statement of the maths problem, so helpers can help you easier. In this case,I just equivocaly guess that the math problem is:  `Let d1, d2 are straight lines passing through  P(-3,-4,-5), Q(2,7,-17) and with normal planes .... , respectively. Find M on d1, N on d2 such that MN is perpendicular to both d1 and d2.`

Comment: Yes, d1 and d2 are lines in 3D. MN is perpendicular to both d1 and d2.